# I don't understand how to write out propositions using only disjunctions and conjunctions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this problem that says:

Suppose the domain of the propositional function P(x, y) consists of pairs x and y, where x = 1,2, or 3, and y = 1,2, or 3. Write the propositions below using disjunctions and conjunctions only.

a) Ǝx P(x, 3)
I did: ORx P(x,3)

b) Ɐy ¬P(2, y)
I did: ANDy ¬P(2,y)

c) Ɐx Ǝy P(x, y)
I did: ANDx ORy P(x,y)

d) Ǝx Ɐy ¬P(x,y)
I did: (ANDy ¬P(1,y)) OR (ANDyP(2,y)) OR (ANDyP(3,y))

but I am not sure if it is good, can somebody help me please

Answer (score 0):

A.  P(1,3) or P(2,3) or P(3,3).
What is Vs supposed to mean?

The others are unreadable because you are using fancy software incompatible with ASCII and Mathjax, the recommended built in language used at the math stack.

Comment: Ok, now I changed it, I am not sure if you understand better now. By the way, I don't know what is ASCII

Comment: @JenniferOsorio ORx and ANDx are meaningless.